# amcl does not publish transforms to "future"

Tags: localization, navigation, rosbag, amcl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rosbag to playback a bag file with messages from `/tf`, `/scan`, and `/initialpose`. I am trying to use `amcl` to localize the robot within that bag. I have set `use_sim_time` to be true.

The problem now is that the localization is not working properly: Even though `tf` messages indicate that the robot should be moving around, the localization from `amcl` is almost fixed around initial pose. I ran `rqt_tf_tree` (see below) and see that the timestamp of tf transforms from `/map` to `/odom` is less than the one from `/odom` to `/base_footprint`. I've tested several times, and it's always like this. According to amcl documentation, amcl publishes future dated transforms. So I believe if I fix the timestamp issue, amcl will work properly.

[image: image description]

Does anyone have any idea why `amcl` is not publishing future dated transforms? How to force it to do so?

Additionally, here is an image with RVIZ showing the TF transforms. The problem is that, `/odom` is not fixed, but `/base_footprint` seems to be fixed.
[image: image description]

I appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243277/amcl-does-not-publish-transforms-to-%22future%22/) by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-07**:
What if you take `amcl` out of the picture (just for debugging purposes) ? Try playing back the bagfile and, in RViz, set the *Fixed Frame* to `odom`. Does the `base_link` move now? Do the `LaserScan` messages make sense?

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2016-09-07**:
Yes. It moves. As expected, `odom` frame drifts over time, so the path taken by the robot is not aligned with the map. `LaserScan` messages make sense as well.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-07**:
Are you publishing clock? `rosbag play <file.bag> --clock` ?

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2016-09-07**:
Well, I published to `/clock` in the bag file. I didn't run `rosbag play` with `--clock` argument. I just tried, but it didn't work either. Particles were just being recomputed again and again at the initial pose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my solution to this situation but not this problem. I switched to `gmapping` to obtain the robot's poses, and it works like a charm.

---

Originally posted by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) with karma: 178 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on 2016-09-29**:
I still would like to use AMCL because I need to reuse the map that I generated for other simulations.